# Pass a value between processes using pipes in a loop

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork

I am trying to build a program that forks 4 child processes. The first child takes a value declared before forking, decrements it then passes it through a tube to the second process. The latter increments the value and passes it to the third one. 3 -> 4, 4 - 1 and so on. The program will end when 0 is reached and exit with the PID of the child that got that 0.

This is what I tried:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t end = 1;
```

First I installed a signal handler:

```
void sighandler(int sig)
{
        (void)sig;
        end = 0;
}
```

Then I assigned the action to `SIGUSR1`:

```
void prepare()
{
        struct sigaction s;
        s.sa_handler = sighandler;
        s.sa_flags = 0;
        sigemptyset(&s.sa_mask);
        sigaddset(&s.sa_mask, SIGUSR1);
        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &s, NULL);
}
```

This is my main:

```
int main()
{

    pid_t cpid, first;
    int status;
    int COUNT = 10;
    int pipes[NPROC];
    prepare();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
            pipe(pipes + 2 * i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NPROC; i++)
    {
            switch (first = fork())
            {
            case -1:
                    perror("fail");
            case 0:
                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                            while (end)
                            {
                                    dup2(pipes[i], 0);
                                    read(pipes[i], &COUNT, sizeof(COUNT));
                                    COUNT--;
                                    if (COUNT < 0)
                                            kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
                                    dup2(pipes[i + 1], 1);
                                    write(pipes[i + 1], &COUNT, sizeof(COUNT));
                                    for (int j = 0; j < NPROC; j++)
                                            close(pipes[j]);
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            while (end)
                            {
                                    dup2(pipes[i - 1], 0);
                                    read(pipes[i - 1], &COUNT, sizeof(COUNT));
                                    COUNT--;
                                    if (COUNT < 0)
                                            kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
                                    dup2(pipes[(i + 2) % NPROC], 1);
                                    write(pipes[(i + 2) % NPROC], &COUNT, sizeof(COUNT));
                                    for (int j = 0; j < NPROC; j++)
                                            close(pipes[j]);
                            }
                    }
                    exit(i);
            }
            printf("Start %d \n", first);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NPROC; ++i)
    {
            cpid = wait(&status);

            if (!WIFEXITED(status))
                    printf("Error in child %d\n", (int)cpid);
            else
                    printf("Finished %d\n", (int)cpid);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The idea is, the program runs, installs the signal handler. The signal handler will, when triggered, stop all children processes and allow them to exit.
Then I fork 4 processes. Each will open and close certain tubes in order to communicate with each other and at the same time, each decrements the value and pass it along. When the value hits 0 a signal will be raised and we will get the process id that sent the signal.
When I run the program, it starts and then it just waits indefinitely...
What am I missing?

Comment: I've been refactoring your program. One issue is that `getppid` [as used] will always return the pid of the parent/main. That is, "level" 0 is main. All children are level 1. For the `getppid` to make any sense, you want the child level to be `i`. That is, the _child_ forks the next child [and the parent/main only forks for the first child]. You'll need to rethink your hierarchy. And, doing `signal` in this way is fraught with problems.

Comment: That said, the reason for the freeze is that the first child (child 0) reads from the pipe. But, nothing has ever been placed there, so it will wait forever. The main/parent must write to the child 0 input pipe before the loop starts.

Comment: I actually meant to send the signal to the parent. And all children to be on level 1. But your answer solved my problem. I wasn't aware of this since I'm not sur know how to debug forks with gdb.

Comment: I think it's a bit more involved than that, but if you're happy, I'm happy. _Side note:_ The usual array for pipe control would be: `int pipes[NPROC][2]`--it's a bit cleaner. Actually, doing something like `struct child { pid_t pid; int pipes[2]; }; struct child childlist[NPROC];` might be even better.